# Unable to ping AWS Windows AMI EC2 instance

Tags: ping, amazon-web-services

I have HTTP, Custom ICMP IPv4, SSH all inbound on security and also on Windows Firewall with Advance Securities enables File and Printer sharing for IPv4 for noth Domain and private.

Why I am unable to ping? I have also installed and started Apache though User Data but unable to HTTP in port 80.

May I know your solution to connect and start Apache?

Comment: It's impossible to understand your question. What is the windows version? Does your instance have a public IP address? What did you set up?

Comment: I am unable to ping public IP (EIP), its an AWS instance created using Win AMI. I am able to connect using remote desktop. I am able to ping google.com but getting time out when pinging public IP of my own instance on AWS.

Comment: As you can connect using RDesktop and ping google.com, your network settings should be OK. Did you allow all ICMP from all sources in the firewall? By default Windows firewall blocks ICMP.

Comment: Yes I have included the same in my security group for all 0.0.0.0./0